# PRIORVALUE func in WFR

Tags: workflow, formula, compile-error

I'm trying to use PRIORVALUE in a workflow where the Evaluation Criteria is: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria.
My workflow should be triggered if:
previous value in case Status (picklist) was Prioritized and if the Account Owner related to the case is not empty.
This is my Rule Criteria (formula evaluates to True):

IF( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Prioritize"),
IF(ISBLANK(Contact.Account.Name), False, True), 
False)

The syntax error I get is: 
Error: Function PRIORVALUE may not be used in this type of formula.

Please advise,
Thanks
Rachel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the document PRIORVALUE function is available only if the evaluation criteria is set to **when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited.**

[image]

[PRIORVALUE function](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#PRIORVALUE)